# Python SQLite3 how to connect single column into multiple tables

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm new into database systems and I struggle with following problem: I have two tables representing HOUSE and APARTMENT and both contains column named *offer* (among many other columns). There are also two tables named SALE and LEASE (each with different columns).

How can I link *offer* column with both tables SALE and LEASE? So every row in HOUSE/APARTMENT will be pointing (through *offer*) to exactly one row in either SALE or LEASE?

Is there something like inheritance in SQLite, which could solve this? Only idea I have is to create new table named OFFER which will have one column to link with SALE, second column to link with LEASE and then this whole table will be linked to SALE's/LEASE's column *offer*. But this solution does not seems clear to me and I hope for something better.

I visualised my problem into diagram:
[problem visualisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4HGv.png)

Thank you for any response.

EDIT: I added APARTMENT table into visualisation, so it is not missleading.

Comment: Why is the _house_ pointing at sales and leases, rather than the other way round? Seems that would solve your problem.

Comment: It would, if there was not APARTMENT table (which is not in visualisation), but there is, so I will have exactly the same problem -> one row in SALE/LEASE will have to point at either APARTMENT or HOUSE.

Comment: You should have an `Offer` table that has foreign keys to all the other tables.  Only the keys that are relevant are non null, otherwise the other key values remain null.  This will allow differentiation and easy selection and joining to each table separately.  (Not all situations can be solved with basic schema.  Sometimes the schema needs to be "complicated" to match the corresponding complexity of the problem.  Single foreign-key relationships are not intended/sufficient to handle alternative relationships.)

Comment: An alternative is to create separate foreign key fields on each table, one for each different type of relationship.  Perhaps conceptually a single column might seem "simpler", but you need some way of differentiating the values in the field and there is no way to define two foreign-key constraints on the same field anyway.  Two fields would allow determination of the type of offer and proper joins to the corresponding tables.

Comment: As the above said - if your relationships aren't exactly 1 to 1 or between different tables (that you might also want to add to in the future) you'll want to represent that relationship as its own table

Comment: I thought about something like that, but was not sure if it is correct solution. Thank you very much, it was very helpful.